# Как вырезать название файла и разбить на переменные через регулярные выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. У меня не совсем стандартная задача по регуляркам. В регулярках нуб, по этому прошу помощи. Имеются названия файлов:

```
02. ГудВин[Герои Комиксов] - Орут сирены(фристайл)
12. Стильный Билли feat. aka Ахмед - Чисто ё (Стильный Билли prod.)
04.Nuttkase feat. Птаха - Если Друг (Хасол-Версия) (Phunk Masta Seven prod.)
02.Dr.MokRolog,Old Primus,JustSmile,Vine Bi - Электрограч (Pro100 Beatz prod.)
```

Необходимо вырезать из загружаемого файла название и с помощью регулярных выражений его обрезать по следующему сценарию:

1. Если название начинается на "01." (цифры и точка, вырезаем их)
2. Берём содержимое до пробела и до дефиса " -", это сохраняем в поле
   artist
3. Берём содержимое после дефиса и пробела "- ", сохраняем это в поле
   name
4. После названия в большинстве случаев идут либо скобки "( )", либо
   квадратные скобки "[ ]", а иногда скобки повторяются. Возможно ли в
   таком варианте первые закрывающиеся скобки добавлять к имени файла,
   а последние брать и вставлять в поле beatmaker?!

Тоесть на выходе должны иметь

```
$artist = 'Стильный Билли';
$feat = 'aka Ахмед';
$name = 'Чисто ё';
$beatmaker = 'Стильный Билли';
```

вот так

```
$artist = 'Nuttkase';
$feat = 'Птаха';
$name = 'Если Друг (Хасол-Версия)';
$beatmaker = 'Phunk Masta Seven';
```

и вот так

```
$artist = 'Dr.MokRolog';
$feat = 'Old Primus,JustSmile,Vine Bi';
$name = 'Электрограч';
$beatmaker = 'Pro100 Beatz';
```

Буду признателен, если здесь https://regex101.com/r/AD860D/1 покажите сразу как вырезать будет.

Comment: Может, `^\d+\.\s*(?P<artist>.*?)(?:\bfeat\.?\s*(?P<feat>.*?))?\s+-\s+(?P<name>.*?)\s*\((?P<beatmaker>[^()]*)\)\s*$`, https://regex101.com/r/qCV3eY/1?

Comment: А можно как-то вырезать prod. ?

Comment: Да, https://regex101.com/r/qCV3eY/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
^\d+\.\s*(?P<artist>.*?)(?:\bfeat\.?\s*(?P<feat>.*?))?\s+-\s+(?P<name>.*?)\s*\((?P<beatmaker>[^()]*?)(?:\s*prod\.)?\)\s*$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/qCV3eY/2)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `\.` - точка
- `\s*`  - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `(?P<artist>.*?)` - 0 и более любых символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `(?:\bfeat\.?\s*(?P<feat>.*?))?` - необязательная последовательность шаблонов:

  - `\bfeat` - целое слово `feat`
  - `\.?` - необязательная точка
  - `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
  - 0 и более любых символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `\s+-\s+` - дефис, с обеих сторон которого могут находиться 1 и более пробельных символов
- `(?P<name>.*?)` - 0 и более любых символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `(?P<beatmaker>[^()]*?)` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `(` и `)`
- `(?:\s*prod\.)?`
- `\)` -  - символ `)`
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: Случайно не вы ставите минусы на мои ответы по регулярным выражениям?